# Another word to substitute "Heck" or "Hell" in these kind of sentences

Tags: idioms, offensive-language

I have been thinking about sentences like, "That's not impressive; Heck, even *I* can do that!" and I was wondering if there was another word that I can use in place of "Heck" in sentences like these or how I can reword the sentence while still keeping the same message across, if it's possible?

Comment: *Heck* is **already** a euphemism (for "Hell"). Have you considered merely leaving it out altogether?—which may even be more effective than something watered down still further.

Comment: Why don't you like them? Too weak, too strong, too Christian, or just want variety? Anything from *gee* to *fuck* might do depending on the situation.

Answer (score -3):

Any sort of interjection or exclamation would work in conversation.

“Shoot, even *I* could do that.”

“Shit, even *I* could do that.”

“Jesus, even *I* could do that.”

Comment: If the euphemism *Heck* is too strong, *shit* and *Jesus* will be too. *Jesus* is arguably strengthening the swearing.

Comment: OP never said anything about _Heck_ being too strong. They asked for "another word I can use in place of" or how to "reword the sentence while still keeping the same message". Question is tagged with `offensive-language` so my suggestions seem fair game.

Comment: The 'offensive-language' probably refers to the original content. It might be rather easier to be offensive than polite – many inarticulate people will pepper every sentence with offensive terms.

Comment: You missed the 4-letter word for fornication

Comment: This entry only ridicules the problem and gives a trivial answer.